# Dynamic Page Title Issue when Sharing Links on WhatsApp/Telegram in Blazor WebApp Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I am encountering an issue with dynamically changing the page title in a Blazor WebaApp (.Net8 / Server) project using JavaScript (I need to dynamically change the  tag because I have a single page that adapts to various articles in my database). While the title is successfully modified on page load, sharing the link on WhatsApp or Telegram does not reflect the updated title in the preview.

It seems that WhatsApp/Telegram detects the page title before the JavaScript code has a chance to update it. As a result, the preview shows the outdated title.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Is there a recommended approach for ensuring that the updated title is correctly detected when sharing links on messaging platforms?

Thank you for your help!

Best regards

Here is the code I am currently using:

Home.razor:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("changeDocumentTitle", "new title");
}
```

App.razor:

```
<script>
    function changeDocumentTitle(newTitle) {
        document.title = newTitle;
        document.getElementById('ogTitle').setAttribute('content', newTitle);
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
I can't dynamically update title using <PageTitle> For example in the following code, when I click on the link, SetParametersAsync is invoked but  is not updated:

```
@page "/{currentId:int}"
<PageTitle>@Title</PageTitle>
<a href="@currentId">Click Here</a>

@code
{    
    public string @currentId;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        Title = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        StateHasChanged();
        return base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting the page title using javascript rather than using Blazor?

Comment: Same problem if you use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/control-head-content?view=aspnetcore-8.0 to set the page title?

Comment: Is the HeadOutlet tag correctly positioned in App.razor?

Comment: @PaulDurant yes, I use <PageTitle>. However, I "solved" it by using <PageTitle> for the first login (so whatsapp/telegram sharing detects the title correctly). To update the title with internal navigation within the same page I use javascript